# When adding a new user to Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace what rights are needed?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a new workspace I created using an administrative account.  The admin user can get into the studio and see everything and is able to run queries against files in the lake. I then followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control) to grant rights to a regular user account. I didn't use a group as directed in the article, just acted as if my user was the WS1_WSAdmins group.

In portal I grant **blob contributor rights on the storage container**.
In studio I grant **workspace admin**.

Going to studio as the user, I can't access the workspace. "You do not have authorization to see this workspace."

In portal I grant **contributor on workspace** and can access workspace - so that fixes the issue, but it doesn't appear to be part of the instructions for setup. I've read the instructions 5 times and don't see anything regarding granting workspace rights to the groups. What am I missing?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been already called out in the document: [Secure your Synapse workspace (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control) (i.e, you need have **Azure role** such as **owner**, **contributor** along with **Synapse roles** such as **Workspace admin**, **SQL admin**, **Apache Spark admin**).

**To secure a Synapse workspace (preview), you'll follow a pattern of configuring the following items:**

- **Azure roles** (such as the built-in ones like **Owner**, **Contributor**, etc.)
- **Synapse roles** – these roles are unique to Synapse and aren't based on Azure roles. There are three of these roles:

  - Synapse **workspace admin**
  - Synapse **SQL admin**
  - Synapse **Apache Spark admin**
- Access control for data (i.e. **storage Blob Data Contributor role**) in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 (ADLSGEN2).